# PHP PDO throwing syntax error, need feedback

Tags: php, pdo

I need a little feedback on why the following is throwing a SYNTAX error of : "unexpected '[', expecting ')'" , it would be the second line in the code below:

```
if($deleteBeforeInsertFieldKey!==false){
    if($deleteQry->execute([$deleteBeforeInsertFieldKey=>$row[$deleteBeforeInsertFieldKey]])===false){
        throw new \Exception('There was a problem deleting a row prior to insert.');
    }
}
```

Comment: This section seems to be fine. Are you sure this is where the error is being thrown? You may need to include more of the surrounding code.

Comment: What is your PHP version? If it's old, it might not be expecting the "new" array syntax (`[]` rather than `array()`).

Comment: Gotcha... let me find out, the environment is hosted on media temple

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.29 ... blah.

Comment: Awesome... that's what is was... thanks my friend!

Comment: No problem. FYI, the (`[]`) syntax was introduced in PHP 5.4, which has been [end of life](http://php.net/eol.php) for over a year now. Hopefully your host can provide something newer; if not I would look for a new host.